# Lost in recursion-How to reverse print user input single chars and multiplying them

Tags: c, recursion

Sorry for being vague, but I am just helpless, been sitting on this for 4 hours :|

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp (int count)
{
    int j = 0;
    char c;
    printf("Enter a char\n");
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
    while(c=='\n');
    if (c == 'x')
        return;
    temp(count+1);
    for (j=0;j <count+1;j++)
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
    return count;
}


int print_in_reverse()
{
    int count = 0;
    temp(0);
    printf("%d\n" , count);

}
```

I am in tears and agony, need to reverse it.

Comment: `print ("%dn", temp(0);)`, you are printing `count = 0`in main. Read about scope, count has local scope

Comment: It still doesn't work...
And in general my result is the opposite of what I need ;(

Comment: @user3445443 He only wanted to refer to that line, not tell you to change it to what he wrote. He merely made typos when writing it out, that's why it's different from yours. In `print_in_reverse()`, you define a variable `count` and set it to `0`, and then later print it out without ever changing it in between. The result can only ever be `0`. You need to realize that the `count` in `print_in_reverse()` is a different `count` than the one in `temp()`.

Comment: At the point where you check whether `c == 'x'`, the value of `c` is a newline - the `do` loop before the check enforces that. Also, switch on your compiler warnings. For example, you have a return without a value when ending the input with `x`. You also don't keep track of the recursion depth, because you don't use the result from `temp`.

Comment: @MOehm The do-loop enforces the opposite: It will loop `while(c=='\n')`, so c *can't* be `\n` when it exits.

Comment: @Medo42: Er, yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so closed to your goal. If you pass `count` as a parameter you get larger value at deeper recursion. Move it to the return so you will get smaller value at deeper recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp ()
{
    int j = 0;
    int count;
    char c;
    printf("Enter a char\n");
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
    while(c=='\n');
    if (c == 'x')
        return 0;
    count = temp(); /* Recursive call. */
    for (j=0;j <count+1;j++)
        putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
    return count+1; /* Return an increased count. */
}

int print_in_reverse()
{
    int count = 0;
    count = temp();
    printf("%d\n" , count);

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!THANK YOU KIND SIR!